# Wrong Data Type while Reading a large Text File

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read the following [file](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/individual+household+electric+power+consumption) using pandas. The code that I'm using is the following:

`df = pd.read_csv("household_power_consumption.txt", header=0, delimiter=';', nrows=5)`

The df.info() is giving the correct output.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 9 columns):
Date                     5 non-null object
Time                     5 non-null object
Global_active_power      5 non-null float64
Global_reactive_power    5 non-null float64
Voltage                  5 non-null float64
Global_intensity         5 non-null float64
Sub_metering_1           5 non-null float64
Sub_metering_2           5 non-null float64
Sub_metering_3           5 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(7), object(2)
memory usage: 440.0+ bytes
```

But when I'm trying to read the entire data set using the same code except `nrows`:

`df_all = pd.read_csv("household_power_consumption.txt", header=0, delimiter=';')` the column types are becoming object.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 2075259 entries, 2006-12-16 17:24:00 to 2010-11-26 21:02:00
Data columns (total 7 columns):
Global_active_power      object
Global_reactive_power    object
Voltage                  object
Global_intensity         object
Sub_metering_1           object
Sub_metering_2           object
Sub_metering_3           float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(6)
memory usage: 126.7+ MB
```

Can anyone please tell me why this is happening? And how to resolve it?

Thanks!

Comment: It's also losing the date and time columns. Are you sure you're using the same command?

Comment: I downloaded and read the file. I get all 9 columns. I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Barmar: It's not taking the date & time column as well. But I'll make them as index column. So not worried about the type of these columns.

Comment: @HarvIpan: Not sure why you can't reproduce the problem. I'm using jupyter notebook with python 3. I'm printing the logs of the command. Also, barmar correctly pointed the reason why I'm getting the issue. It's because of "?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that when you read the full data set in there are values in the additional rows that are being interpreted as different data types, for example floats interpreted as integers. You can specify the data types explicitly using the `dtype` argument in `read_csv` - see docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Alternatively you could try to force the data types after loading the data; e.g. like so:

```
df["Global_active_power"] = df["Global_active_power"].astype(float)
```

Comment: This is correct. There are lots of lines with `?` in place of the data values.

Comment: E.g. `21/12/2006;11:23:00;?;?;?;?;?;?;`

Comment: @Toby: Thanks for your answer! After trying your option, I was getting this error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '?'`. As Barmar correctly pointed out, there are lots of "?". In `SAS` or `R`, these values are taken as `NA`. How to resolve it in case of Pandas?

Comment: @Beta If all the bad values are represented as a single question mark you could just replace them with NaN before converting the datatypes: df = df.replace("?", np.nan)